# Looking for a system to handle internal control execution

Tags: tasks, security-policy

We are a fast growing company that needs to suddenly meet requirements by external auditors, in order to pass IT security guidelines. As part of the guidelines, we need to ensure that various internal controls are executed. Since the control execution must be tamper proof, even admins in our company may not have the rights to edit or delete control procedures after they are completed (to preserve the correct history).

Examples of processes that must keep an auditable history:

- access to an internal tool granted to an employee
- permission to complete some work is given to an employee
- a weekly routine check is completed and the result is recorded by the responsible person

It seems that we need to rely on an external company to store our data and give us only limited access to it, in order to ensure compliance. Am I on the right track here? As I heard, every publicly traded company in the US must pass audits which have the same requirement, so I hope there is a standard procedure to follow.

Comment: This is just a duplicate of [(closed) Looking for task manager to handle internal control execution](https://superuser.com/questions/1666462/closed-looking-for-task-manager-to-handle-internal-control-execution) and is still a request for a 'product, service or learning material recommendations'. If you need advice on legal compliance, speak to your lawyer.

Comment: I really tried to change the question to be more general and shed a light on these audit requirements. If it still isn't allowed on here, I apologize for wasting time. However, where can I ask this question? Is there a different StackExchange community that allows for it? I'm sure a lawyer won't be able to answer it either.

Comment: If your lawyer doesn't know what to do to ensure legal compliance, you need a different lawyer. There's nowhere on stack exchange to cover something this broad.

Comment: It's not like that. The lawyer/advisor came back with the info that we need this immutable task management system for internal controls. However, I've scanned the market and I don't see any of the task management systems provide this feature! So I am wondering how others are tackling the same requirements. Who knows, maybe our advisor is completely wrong and he is raising a non-issue?

Comment: You could TRY https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks @spikey_richie! For future reference, here is the link to my question over there: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/80075/looking-for-a-system-for-internal-control-execution